# My Strategy Doesn't Executive Trades , How to Fix It?

Tags: pine-script

I'm testing a new strategy however after I've clicked "Add to Chart" , no trade is made. May I know how to solve it ? Thanks !

```
//@version=4
strategy("Breakout 3 Weeks High")

Long1 = ema(close, 150) > ema(close, 200)
Long2 = sma(close, 50) > ema(close, 150)
Long3 = ema(close, 21) > sma(close, 50)
Long4 = close > ema(close, 21)
Long5 = crossover(close, high[15])
AvgVol = sum(volume, 50)
Long6 = volume > AvgVol * 1.5
OutofTrade = strategy.position_size <= 0
TimePeriod = time > timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2010, 01, 01, 0, 0)

if(Long1 and Long2 and Long3 and Long4 and Long5 and Long6 and OutofTrade)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    
if strategy.position_size != 0
    StopLoss = strategy.position_avg_price * 0.97
    TakeProfit =strategy.position_avg_price * 1.09
    strategy.exit("Exit", "Long", stop=StopLoss, limit=TakeProfit)
```

Answer (score 0):

No trades are made because you are checking if all of the "longs" are true at the same time. The probability of them all being true at the same time is very low. Writing "or" between the statements, makes the program trade.

Change:

```
if(Long1 and Long2 and Long3 and Long4 and Long5 and Long6 and OutofTrade)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
```

To:

```
if(Long1 or Long2 or Long3 or Long4 or Long5 or Long6 or OutofTrade)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot , Bro ! But when I screen stocks by the above criteria , I could screen a lot. Why the probability is so low ? I mean , in reality , I could see lots times.